# Error: unexpected '}' in "}" i while running this chunk of R code

Tags: r, syntax-error

**While running the following code I get the error: unexpected '}' in "}"**

However, there are no open double or single brackets

```
df3["Zone"]<-1
usq<-0
for(i in 1:nrow(df3)){ 
  if(df3$state = "Kerala"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SW")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Karnataka"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SW")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Goa"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SW")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Maharashtra"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "NW")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Gujarat"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "NW")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Tamilnadu"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SE")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Andhra Pradesh"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SE")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Pondicherry"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "SE")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "Orissa"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "NE")
  }
  else if(df3$state = "West Bengal"){
    paste(df3$Zone[i] <- "NE")
  }
  usq<- print(df3)
  df3.1<-data.frame(usq)
}
```

I would also like to know how to write a single if statement for each zones ie for states Kerala, Karnataka and Goa it should paste 'SW' and so on other zones

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax for comparisons in R is `==` not `=`. Then, `df3$state = "Kerala"` compares a *vector" to a string... not sure if that works. Also, I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do, but I can't figure out what the purpose of the final three lines  is.

Comment: This looks like you want to join tables. Please give us some rows of `df3`

Comment: The error you've got doesn't seem to be caused by the code presented. Creating an example df3, then running your code, the first error is `Error: unexpected '=' in: "for(i in 1:nrow(df3)){  if(df3$state ="` cause by using `=` when you need `==`. The source of your error seems to be elsewhere, or caused by only running part of the code

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your first issue but to combine if statements, you can use the or operator "||"

else if((df3$state == "Karnataka") || (df3$state == "Kerala") || ...)

Not too familiar with R but that should work

Comment: It is even easier. We can write `if (var %in% c("a", "b", "c") {...}`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add new columns based on data which can be structured in other tables, joining is the way to go:

```r
library(tidyverse)
zones <- tibble(state = c("Karnataka", "Kerala"), zone = c("SW", "SW"))
zones
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   state     zone 
#>   <chr>     <chr>
#> 1 Karnataka SW   
#> 2 Kerala    SW
df3 <- tibble(state = c("Kerala", "Karnataka"))
df3
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   state    
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 Kerala   
#> 2 Karnataka
df3 %>% left_join(zones)
#> Joining, by = "state"
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   state     zone 
#>   <chr>     <chr>
#> 1 Kerala    SW   
#> 2 Karnataka SW
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>